# Add Cocos3D to existing XCode/iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, graphics, shared-libraries, cocos3d

So I've recently successfully installed **Cocos3D** on my computer and I am able to create new "iOS" projects in xCode using the **Cocos3D** starter template. However, I currently don't need to start a new project. I just need to be able to integrate **Cocos3D** into an existing "iOS" project I am developing, the reason mostly being that the app for the most part will be a "typical" iOS app but only a handful of `views/view controllers` need to be able to handle **3D graphics**.

So does anybody here know an easy way to do this or can point me in the direction of an (easy to follow) tutorial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will become much easier after the next release of Cocos3D in the next few weeks.

But for now, have a look at the `CC3DemoMultiScene` demo app. It shows you how to integrate Cocos3D into an app that uses Storyboards.

That demo also shows how to release all caches and completely shut down OpenGL ES in between displaying scenes. You may or may not want to take it that far.